# Why is the cop deliberately involved with the final part of the sting?

Tags: the-sting

In *The Sting*, Snyder who knows Hooker by his right name hustles Lonnegan out of the fake race parlor. Important to the entire sting was that Lonnegan never finds out that he has been taken. But suddenly these two are thrust together -- what if they chat and Lonnegan realizes that Hooker has been lying about his name the entire time?

This seems to be a major flaw in the entire plan. Lonnegan has very long tentacles, is certainly not going to forget about losing the half million.

Comment: There are multiple cons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sting#Plot .

Answer (score 4):

There were two reasons that the cop (Snyder) was suckered into the con:

1. As a "loose cannon," he could have blown the con by exposing Hooker
   or otherwise throwing a monkeywrench into the works. By making him
   believe that the "Feds" were in control, and by having the (fake)
   "Feds" intimidate Snyder into co-operating, the con-men were able to
   neutralize him as a threat to their con.
2. As long as they already had Snyder under control, they
   might as well also use him for the "blow-off." By having Lonnegan
   get escorted out of the premises by Snyder (whom he knows to be a
   legitimate member of the police), the con-men boost the
   verisimilitude of their con. Presumably, Snyder takes Lonnegan to a
   secluded place, convinces him that the "Feds" were in control, and
   also makes it clear to him that his (Snyder's) "best bet" would be
   to swallow the loss, lay low for a time, and refrain from asking too
   many questions (using those "feelers" that you refer to) - unless he
   wants to face hard time in a federal penitentary. ALSO: Remember
   that, early in the film, Lonnegan explains to one of his henchmen
   that even the mere *appearance* of weakness would ruin his
   reputation among other gangsters and spell his doom.

Comment: I understand why he was brought in but I also am saying that Snyder knowing Hooker by a different name could easily say something to Lonnegan that would make him suspicious. If Lonnegan says "Kelly" was shot and Snyder says, No, his name was Hooker, he is well-known grifter around here, that would be it, the bean would have been spilled.

Comment: >>Snyder knowing Hooker by a different name could easily say something to Lonnegan that would make him suspicious. If Lonnegan says "Kelly" was shot and Snyder says, No, his name was Hooker, he is well-known grifter<< We can safely assume that the fellow con-artists and friends of Hooker and Gondorff posing as FBI agents carefully coached Snyder as to what he could and could not say to Lonnegan.

Comment: good point. I suspect I will never be a successful con artist. Seems like a dangerous and complex business.

Comment: On the other hand, coached or not, Snyder now has access as a corrupt cop to a major mobster. In real life, Hooker and Gondorf would be looking over their shoulders for the remainder of their probably short lives. They probably should have shot Lonnegan. I sure would have.